# Op-amp gives attenuated output

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am using an [OPA547](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sbos056) high voltage and high current op-amp.

- V+ = 15 V
- V- = GND or -15 V
- Ilim is shorted with V-
- Vout has a fb resistor of 1K. The output load is a 50-ohm resistor
- Vin+ = 0 V (GND)
- Vin- is connected to 2 Vpp 1 KHz sine with dc offset -2.5 V through a 1K resistor

[image]

I am using it as inverting amplifier with unity gain. The expected output is supposed to be a sine signal with 2 Vpp with an offset of +2.5 V, but the actual output is

Case i) V+ = +15 V and V- = GND

[image]

Case ii) V+ = +15 V and V- = -15 V

[image]

Can anyone guess what could be the problem?

Comment: Vin+ must be at a higher voltage, you have grounded the gate of one side of your diff. pair and left no room for the current source since everything is at 0 volts. To give you a hint, measure the voltage at your virtual ground.

Comment: One detail you should disclose is the frequency of the input sine wave.

Comment: There is a schematic editor built in to the editor.  It is fairly easy to use.  The icon looks like components in parallel or Ctrl-M is the hotkeys.

Comment: @ErnestoG The voltage at Vin+ is 0 V. Do you suggest connecting Vin+ to GND through a 1k resistor?

Comment: @KishoreKumarS, no. What you need to do is define the common-mode voltage of your input. I asked for the voltage at V-.

Comment: VG1 doesn't appear to have a negative 2.5 volts bias.

Comment: @Andyaka The DC offset is set at the function generator. It is explicitly showed in the GUI window.

Comment: @ErnestoG The common mode input is 42 mV with zero offset. The output voltage is 400 mV with 1.2 V offset.

Comment: Per the data sheet the Input Voltage Range (negative) is:   (V-) - 0.2 for linear operation.

Comment: It could be that you've destroyed your opamp when you had V- tied to ground: under Absolute Maximum Ratings you have "Input Voltage .................................................. (V–) – 0.5V to (V+) + 0.5V". Try with a new opamp this time respecting the allowed range of the inputs.

Comment: It works in simulation, as it should from simple theory so *you* are doing something wrong, have destroyed a part in the past, or the parts are not what you say (or think) they are. Impossible to tell which it is without more information, obviously.

Comment: Thanks @Rahmany for the comment. As you have suggested I could have supplied negative input when V- is tied to GND. This could have damaged the IC.